# Internet Explorer Address Space

Tags: c, windows, winapi, internet-explorer, memory

Though i'm currently interested in internet explorer address space i wouldn't mind a general answer. The question is how can i calculate the address space ( and by address space a mean the minimum and maximum address in memory -correct me if i'm wrong- ) of a windows process.
 Actually is this space fixed or varied ? Also do i get to know the virtual or the physical address space , and if the one i get is the visual is it the mapping the same for every instance of the IE i open ?
 I do have a debugger ( ollydbg to be specific ) and i suppose i could get some information from it but i can't specify what and how. Please bear my lack of knowledge, thank you.

Comment: I suspect you are not asking the question you really want to ask. Why do you need to find the minimum and maximum user-mode addresses? You can do this easily by calling GetSystemInfo, but what are you trying to achieve? Also, what do you mean by "physical memory"? User-mode programs don't deal with physical memory directly.

Comment: The reason i wan't to do this is because i want to plot some information across the address space. I didn't know that user-mode programs only deal with virtual memory.
So what i really want to get is the boundaries of the address space of the windows explorer (eg 0x222ef to 0xffffff ) to set as boundaries to my axis and also that these addresses correspond to the same memory segments so as for my measurements to have meaning.

Comment: In any case would the "Memory Map" window pane's "Address" column, while i debug (with ollydbg) answer my question ?

Comment: Use VirtualQueryEx to loop through the memory regions. (Sorry, no time to post a full answer.)

Comment: @laertis: Are you after something like [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx)?

Comment: What are you going to do with your plot? In general, applications shouldn't be snooping on each other.

Answer (score 2):

As wj32 commented, user-mode applications deal only with virtual memory. They are all given the same virtual address space which is usually around 2GB in size (can be configured otherwise, common for DB servers). The exact addresses can be obtained using `GetSystemInfo`. For example, on my system, this is what I get:

```
Python 2.6.3
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetSystemInfo()
(0, 4096, 65536, 2147418111, 3L, 2, 586, 65536, (6, 5898))
```

The 3rd and 4th resulted values indicate the min/max memory addresses, so from a user-mode perspective all processes get 65536-2147418111 as their address space, roughly 2GB. However, I don't think this information will help you very much. If you're looking for pages with specific attributes within the address space of the process, you could use `VirtualQueryEx` (as wj32 commented again). The behavior of `VirtualQueryEx` allows you to call it multiple times, starting from the process min address and incrementing according to the previous call result, and get a complete view of the target process memory space.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generally speaking, all applications in the Windows operating systems work with virtual memory. Virtual memory is feature that heavy rely to the hardware support from the processor side. Once this feature will be enabled, processor will handle all memory accesses by address translation according to the information in page tables defined by kernel. But on the other hand we can claim that all applications in Windows works with physical memory, because processor can execute the code and handle the data only if they resides in the RAM, also called physical memory.

   Virtual memory is just a feature that allows flrxible manipulation on the memory address translation. The kernel mode application differ from the user mode application only in that kernel mode application have access to the page tables and by this can influence to the memory access address translation into the natural physical memory address. In contrast, User mode application haven't this rights, because it will broke all system reliability and securety.
2. According to the Windows design all application processes (including IE) share the same address space layout, where:

   - Some small portion of the low virtual addresses is reserved for catching NULL pointer dereferencing. Attempt to access this region will lead to the access violation error.
   - Some huge portion of high addresses is reserved for the kernel mode code. That region isn't accesible from the user mode application and shared by all processes in the system.
   - Part in the middle targeted to the application code and data. And each process in the system has its own layout of that region that implicitly use its own physical memory.

   If the small portion in the start is looks like have a constant size of 64 Kb. The border between application and kernel parts of address space can resides in two locations. The first one is widespread default border that assign 2Gb of addresses on the top of address space to the kernel. But the Windows kernel can be launched with special parameter that reduces the size of the kernel part of address space to 1Gb. This kernel config typically used on the servers that runs databases, because bdatabase application want to have as big as possible address space part due to the performance reasons.
3. Layout of the Application part of the process address space seems to be relatively stable. It can slightly change in dependence of the application config and application activities. This is true for the all Windows systems up to the Vista. Starting from Windows Vista Microsoft applies the ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization). The purpoce of that feature is to broke described above similarity of the address space of all processes that execute the same application. This feature applied due to the security reasons.
4. To get the process memory layout use already mentioned by other guys WinAPI system calls:

   - `GetSystemInfo()` - To get information about application part of
     address spaces boundaries.
   - `VirtualQueryEx()` - To get the general informtion about address space layout.
   - Other functions of WinAPI to get more detailed information about address space regions in dependence of its types. Look in MSDN for
     details.

Answer (score 0):

Yonilevy is correct. User-mode application can only see virtual memory. So all applications have a uniform address space. The OS and MMU(memory management unit) will translate the virtual memory address to physical address. If the physical address is not cached in physical memory, it will fetch from hard disk.